# Is it possible to rotate object as fast as the linear velocity of point on surface become greater than speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, velocity, rotation

Is it possible? Or the rotation also cause the increasing of the object mass and energy needed for acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

As the speed of a point on the periphery approaches the speed of light, the centripetal acceleration trying to pull the object to pieces increases without bound. In practical terms, any object will explode if you spin it fast enough, and that explosion happens long before the peripheral speed is high enough for you to even think about relativistic effects.

Comment: I was reading this article https://www.sciencealert.com/einstein-s-cross-is-helping-measure-the-spin-of-distant-supermassive-black-holes that shows the accretion disks of quasars spinning at 70% of c.  So I'm wondering if your answer about centripetal acceleration is correct.  I have no doubt that it can't reach c because of the energy required, but I don't know if "explode" from mere force is correct.    Gravity is pretty darned strong.

Comment: @foolishmuse Accretion disks consist of large numbers of small objects - much like an object that has already exploded.

Comment: What is about black holes?

Comment: @Robotex, What is what about black holes? Are you asking, about the case where the object in you question _is_ a black hole? There are no points on the surface of a black hole because a black hole does not have a surface.

Comment: @SolomonSlow "black hole does not have a surface" - we don't know it

Comment: What if black hole rotating so fast. Will it explode?